# Subtract one from integer displayed in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that adds one to its value -- basically it counts up -- when a button is pressed. Could someone please help me with a minus button? That way if the user accidentally presses the add button more than they needed, they can subtract their mistake. I've tried this, but the label's text is set to -1 now. and I want it to just subtract one each time its pressed:

```
- (IBAction)subtractButton:(id)sender {
    static int integerSaved;
    integerSaved = integer;
    integerSaved -= 1;
    [label2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", integerSaved]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)subtract
{
   label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [label2.text intValue]-1];
}
```

This code assumes that you are not using Interface Builder, and that you are manually linking "subtract" to the UIButton.  If you are using Interface Builder, try this code.

```
-(IBAction)subtract:(id)sender
{
   label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [label2.text intValue]-1];
}
```

I have not tested this but I think it should work.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)subtractButton:(id)sender {
[label2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[label2.text intValue] - 1]];
}
```

Comment: ok i tried this but I'm getting an error and its pointing to the last "]" after the -1 and it just says "Expected identifier". do u know whats wrong with the code? I couldn't figure it out?

Comment: You've got an extra bracket before "NSString".  Take that out and this should work now that intValue is called on the NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Using the value of the `UIView` instance to do arithmetic is not the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)-way. You should really be separating your data model from your view.

Expose an `int`, `NSInteger` or `NSNumber` property in a class somewhere, where that class is dedicated to holding data values for your app.

When a touch event comes in for a given button, increment the data property and fire a notification that updates the view based on what's in the property. Or add an [observer](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/kvo-and-iphone-sdk.html) to the property. The observer then updates the view when the property value changes.

Following the MVC pattern would be a more "Apple"-ish or "iOS"-ish way of doing things, than getting the `UIView`'s value, converting it to an integer, and then converting it back to a string.